# Excel VBA get the name of the next sheet after current

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Is there a way in Excel VBA to get the name of the next sheet following the `ActiveSheet` ?

For example let's presume that my spreadsheet has 4 sheets and I would like to create a macro which inserts in the current worksheet (`Sheet1` in this case) the name of the next spreadsheet (`Sheet2`). Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Activesheet.Index` will give you the position of the active sheet, so:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1")= ActiveSheet.Parent.Sheets(Activesheet.Index + 1).Name
```

You should add a check that the activesheet isn't the last one...

Answer (score 1):

Just a little sample here.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, shprv As Worksheet, shnext As Worksheet
//make sure that use "as Worksheet" after every variable you declare

Set sh = ActiveSheet     //always use "Set" before since these variables are "Object type", only by this their values can be set correctly
Set shprv = sh.Previous
Set shnext = sh.Next
```

In this case, the value of `sh` will be `Sheet1` as the picture you gave,
and the value of `shnext` will be `Sheet2`.
But `shprv` will have no value since there is no sheet before `Sheet1`.